# How to Center Align the iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to center align the iframe, but it is coming left aligned, here is my code
(Below piece of code will run on large displays, the height, width is unknown)

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cast - Main Page</title>
    <style>
        body {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        overflow-x:hidden;

        }
        .iframe {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding:0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="imagegallery.html" class="iframe" id="mainframe"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't even try the basic things like `align` or `text-align` so how you expect it to be aligned?

Comment: have you tried applying width and height in the html `iframe` tag? because that always works for me

Comment: Well if you want to display that iframe itself in the centre, add: `display:block; margin:0 auto;` Also to do that, width needs to be in pixels or less than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in a div and apply px; works for me

Comment: While this may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.